# Java JScrollPane- Multiple components

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm trying to add 2 images inside the JScrollPane. the first image is a background and the second one overlap the first one. The problem shows only the second image when i run my program!

**please help**

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("mini_map.png");
JLabel label1=new JLabel(ii);

Icon icon = new ImageIcon("Mg.gif");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel(icon);

JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane();

jsp.getViewport().add(label1);
jsp.getViewport().add(label2 );
```

Answer (score 7):

JViewport is a single-child container, you can't add two components.

To achieve an overlap (that is stack components in z-direction) in *any* container, you'r mostly on your own, the built-in support is poor. Either have to manage them in LayeredPane (as mentioned already) or try OverlapLayout

Comment: +1 @kleopatra the OverlapLayout looks as it is a very useful manager. Thanks I didn't know of it. It could be nicely used to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Put both labels in the same panel and add it to the JScrollPane:

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("mini_map.png");
JLabel label1=new JLabel(ii);

Icon icon = new ImageIcon("Mg.gif");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel(icon);

JPanel pContainer = new JPanel();
pContainer.add(label1);
pContainer.add(label2);
JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(pContainer);
```

Comment: This would align the components beside or above/below each other, rather than satisfy the 'overlap' requirement.

Comment: This is true, I missed the part when wrote he want them to overlap, but yet he cannot assign 2 components to JScrollPane.

Comment: "..missed the part.." Sometimes I am so busy editing a post from a dog's breakfast of unformatted code to something readable that I will miss the subtle details.  Have trouble distinguishing the 'forest from the trees'.  ;)  As an aside, thanks for making the post readable so others (like me) could then spot those finer details.  :)

Comment: The title didn't mention the overlap requirement, and I didn't Google for overlapping things, so +1 for answering what I was Googlig for.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have components on top of each other use a [layered pane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it for your particular problem.

Since you say you have one image which serves the role of a background, thus I would override paintComponent() like in BackgroundPanel below. 
This way you have a panel which serves as a background only. To it you can add any type of component, in your case a JLabel with an ImageIcon.

This way you have an effect of one being over another and you are still able to use layout manager to control where your components are.

If your problem is more complex or you want to generally set Components one over another then do as all are saying here ---> use JLayeredPane. Note that if you use JLayeredPane sadly layout managers will not help you since it doesn't respects them. You will have to proceed similarly to a situation when you use a null manager, i.e. setBounds() for components.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PaintInScroll
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Image backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(new URL(
                            "http://www.jvsearch.com/adidocs7_images/JAVAORANGE.JPG")).getImage();
                    BackgroundPanel bP = new BackgroundPanel(backgroundImage);
                    bP.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    bP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL(
                            "https://blogs.oracle.com/theplanetarium/resource/thumb-java-duke-guitar.png")));
                    bP.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(bP);
                    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
                    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setContentPane(contentPane);
                    f.setSize(800, 600);
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }catch(MalformedURLException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(PaintInScroll.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel
{
    private Image image;

    public BackgroundPanel(Image image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Images are URLs thus i-net connection is required to run the example.

**EDIT1:** Example showing how to use JLayeredPane with use of layout managers for each layer.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PaintInScrollRespectingLayoutManagers extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    private JLabel imageContainer = new JLabel();
    private JButton infoB = new JButton("i");
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public PaintInScrollRespectingLayoutManagers(ImageIcon image)
    {
        super();
        this.imageContainer.setIcon(image);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imageContainer);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 90));
        JPanel iSPP = new JPanel();//image scroll pane panel
        iSPP.setOpaque(false);
        iSPP.add(scrollPane);
        JPanel iBP = new JPanel();//info button panel
        iBP.setOpaque(false);
        iBP.add(infoB);
        this.layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.add(iSPP, new Integer(50));
        layeredPane.add(iBP, new Integer(100));
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(layeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(new JButton("A button"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        layeredPane.addComponentListener(layeredPaneCL);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    }
    private ComponentListener layeredPaneCL = new ComponentAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
        {
            super.componentResized(e);
            System.out.println("componentResized");
            for(Component c : layeredPane.getComponents())
                c.setSize(layeredPane.getSize());
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new PaintInScrollRespectingLayoutManagers(new ImageIcon(new URL(
                            "http://www.prodeveloper.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/stackoverflow-logo-250.png"))));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }catch(MalformedURLException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(PaintInScrollRespectingLayoutManagers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**NOTE 2:** The only reason that the scroll panes have setPrefferedSize is so you can see the scrollbars. Otherwise do not use it let the layout take care of controlling scroll pane.