# Dynamically change the cell height in JTable with a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I run into a problem where I have a JTable laid out using GridBagLayout manager and the number of rows in the table is not fixed. I intend to fill the space assigned to the table with all its cells, however there is a big blank (and white) space between the last row of the table and the next component in the container.

As a potential solution, I wonder if I can adjust the height of the cells to fill the space assigned to the table. So for example, if there are three rows, then the height of the space should be equally divided into three rows. If there is only one row, then this row should take up the whole space available.

Any suggestion are welcome, and if there is a better way to achieve the desired effect, please enlighten me. Thanks.

P.S. I am using JTable within a JPanel instead of a JScrollPane, if that makes any difference.

Edit: So I've tried the following code, which certainly adjusts height of the rows depending on the number of the rows present, but it still leaves a blank white space after the last row and before the next component. Wondering why?

```
// re-size the header and row height to fill the whole tPanel
int panelHeight = tPanel.getHeight();
int desiredRowHeight = panelHeight / (numOfRows + 1);
friendsInfo.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(table.getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth(), desiredRowHeight));
table.setRowHeight(desiredRowHeight);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Just set the row heights. You would have to use something like [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/RowHeight.html). Obviously I assume here that your panel has a 'constant' size. Otherwise the layout will make sure to resize it to appropriate size, i.e. table size.

If yes, then you can use the panel height for your calculations of the height each row should take.

**EDIT1:**
Below is an example showing how it might be used to do so using GridBagLayout. I did all to make it look as best as possible though still it has a strange behaviour (for a short time it gets minimal size) when you making the frame smaller. But then again it might be default behaviour for the layout which I am not aware of.

***NOTE:** I am not an expert in using this layout manager (personally I hate it). Thus if there are some parameters which should/shouldn't be set please do let me know (and feel free to edit the answer).*

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

public class TableRowResizeTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {   
                final JTable table = new JTable(3,3);
                final JTableHeader tHeader = table.getTableHeader();
                final JPanel tPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                tPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                ComponentListener cL = new ComponentAdapter() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
                    {
                        super.componentResized(e);
                        // re-size the header and row height to fill the whole tPanel
                        int panelHeight = tPanel.getHeight();
                        int numOfRows = table.getRowCount();
                        int desiredRowHeight = panelHeight / (numOfRows + 1);
                        int gap = panelHeight - desiredRowHeight * (numOfRows + 1);
                        tHeader.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(tHeader.getPreferredSize().width, 
                                desiredRowHeight+gap));
                        tHeader.revalidate();
                        tHeader.repaint();
                        if(desiredRowHeight <1)
                            desiredRowHeight = 1;
                        table.setRowHeight(desiredRowHeight);
                        table.revalidate();
                        table.repaint();
                        System.out.println("tPanel componentResized p.h="+tPanel.getHeight()
                            +"; desiredRowHeight="+desiredRowHeight+"; gap="+gap);
                    }                   
                };
                tPanel.addComponentListener(cL);
                GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 0;
                c.weighty = 1.0;
                tPanel.add(tHeader, c);
                c.gridy = 1;
                c.weighty = 0.0;
                tPanel.add(table,c);
                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                contentPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
                contentPane.add(tPanel);
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setContentPane(contentPane);
                f.setSize(800, 600);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                System.out.println("before f.setVisible p.h="+tPanel.getHeight());
                f.setVisible(true); 
                System.out.println("after f.setVisible p.h="+tPanel.getHeight());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Boro, so I tried calling jPanel.getHeight() but it returns 0 hence I cannot carry out the next steps... Any reason why?

Comment: @skyork it might return zero but on start since it was not layed out in parent component. But you can call [panel.getPreferredSize().getHeight()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize())  on start. Afterwards you should use [getHeight()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getHeight()) since you are after the current size. If it is still fuzzy to you please check description of this methods in Java doc.

Comment: @skyork [Example of using setPreferredSize()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840075/java-jscrollpane-multiple-components/5842383#5842383) which you might need at start to force your panel to be larger then preferred sizes of its children. Where I am using it to make scroll panes intentionally to small so the scroll bars will be shown.

Comment: @Boro please see the edit part above. I think whether the getHeight() returns zero depends on where in the code you call the method. I place it after setContentPane(somePane) and setVisible(true), and it returns a non-zero value though I am not sure if it is the correct one.

Comment: @Boro also, I wonder if the blank space has something to do with the layout manager (BorderLayout) used for the panel which contains the table header (NORTH) and the table itself (CENTER)...

Comment: @skyork Yes it might have something to do with layout manager but without the code I cannot be certain. It also might have something to do with borders which are on the components. Can you possibly provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing your problem?

Comment: @skyork Taking another look at the code I think the result of a small gap at the bottom is rounding when dividing ints. Example: tPanel height is 90 we have 3 rows and 1 header (we can treat it as if we had 4 rows). Thus 90/4 = 22.5, but in Java it gives 22 thus the gap will be 2. Hope this is it :) How you can solve it? Give the additional space to table header.

Comment: @skyork I have added an example into my answer, where I also add the gap to the table header. In result the whole height is always taken. When it goes to a time since when you can start using getHeight() is after the component has been lay out, which happens when you call setVisible(true).