# Is there a possibility to have a footer in a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager

Does anybody know if it is possible to have a "column footer" in a JScrollPane. By default it is possible to set a column header but not a footer.

I already found a library that offers this possibility (JideScrollPane). But unfortunately the lib is not for free and I only need a little part of it.

So I'm asking you guys if there is a way to add this footer. Preferred without creating a custom layout.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: as a suggestion, is it possible to use two jscrolpane ? May be you can use the second one as a footer

Comment: Read [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840075/java-jscrollpane-multiple-components) , I think it can help you.

Comment: Out of box, no. You could take a look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Swing-Library/jide-oss-2.8.3/com/jidesoft/swing/JideScrollPane.java.htm) which adds row and column footer support

Comment: Actually as I searched, JideScrollPane looks like its an open source project. [JideScrollPane.java](https://java.net/projects/jide-oss/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/com/jidesoft/swing/JideScrollPane.java)

Comment: Actually JideScrollPane is from http://www.jidesoft.com. I don't know why the souces are available on the internet.
Take a look at their prices and you'll see this is no free software ;-(